# Testing and editing JavaScript (both standalone and in HTML) in SciTE?

Tags: javascript, html, scite

Whenever I try to run a '.js' file in SciTE (Scintilla Text Editor) I almost always get an error stating that certain variables are undefined. I'm guessing that SciTE doesn't have many JavaScript libraries, but I'm not sure.

A few searches yielded me [these](http://blog.dotsmart.net/2007/12/19/editing-and-testing-scripts-in-scite/) [two](http://blog.scriptoid.com/2010/07/run-javascript-from-scite.html) blog posts on how to get SciTE to print JavaScript test to its output, rather than just opening a web browser when you press F5 to test the code.

I tried them both, but I either got the same errors as before with the first post's solution, or I got an error that said "'jrunscript' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" with the second method.

So, is it possible to test JavaScript code in SciTE and print the JavaScript output (or errors) to SciTE's output?

Simple example code I've tried:

console.log("test")

The error message I received for this: 'Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'console' is undefined'

Comment: Can you give us a simple snippet of code that you expect to run? From looking at that post it runs the javascript with the system script executer (cscript). Are you expecting it to have access to the browser DOM or something like that, if so I don't think it is going to...

Comment: Sorry about that. I added a simple console.log() line.

Comment: Maybe poke around the SciTE settings to see if you can use a different runtime for running standalone Javascript files? Node.js provides the `console.log` API for instance.

Answer (score 3):

**What is SciTe?**

SciTE is a SCIntilla based *Text Editor*. Lua is embedded with SciTe which allows you to access the Scintilla API.

```
# lua code example
`command.go.*.js=jrunscript $(FileNameExt)`
```

**How to run js code in SciTe?**

Create a file called `testConsole.js` with the following content.

```
var console = console || {};
console.log = ( console.log || function( str ){
    if( typeof print == "function" ){
        print( "LOG: " + str + "\n" );
    }
    return "LOG: " + str;
});
console.log( "Javascript works." );
```

Open `testConsole.js` in SciTe.

To run the code, press `F5` or click `Tools` > `Go`.

An output window should appear showing

`LOG: Javascript works.`

**How do I configure SciTe to run javascript?**

I'm using SciTe 3.2.0. Located [here](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/scintilla/wscite320.zip?download)
In `wscite\wsite320\cpp.properties` at line: 424 
change: 
`command.go.*.js=cscript /nologo $(FileNameExt)` 

to:
`command.go.*.js=jrunscript $(FileNameExt)`

if you want to use node.js, then change it to
`command.go.*.js=node $(FileNameExt)`

Make sure that you have the jrunscript or node in your path for the environment variables.
Tutorial [here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

**Do I have `jrunscript`?**

Here's the easiest way to check.
Open up run > type in `cmd` > type `jrunscript`.
`js>` should appear on the screen.

`jrunscript.exe` should be located here.
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin\jrunscript.exe`

Download the lastest [Java SDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) if you can't find it.

**Error Messages**

**What does `'Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'console' is undefined'`**

This means Microsoft JScript ran your javascript and couldn't find the variable console.
Define console to get rid of the error message.

```
var console = console || {};
console.log = ( console.log || function( str ){
    if( typeof print == "function" ){
        print( "LOG: " + str + "\n" );
    }
    return "LOG: " + str;
});
```

Microsoft JScript might be located here:
`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\jsc.exe`

**Error:** `Input Error: There is no file extension in "location"`

Solution: You need to configure the cpp.properties file for javascript.

**Error:** `script file test is not found`

Solution: Rename the file. Make sure that it doesn't have any spaces.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, Larry Battle. It's strange -- I have the latest Java SDK installed on my computer in the same sort of path. I even have jrunscript (I tested it with console.log() and other basic JS to make sure it works). But when I changed line 424 in SciTE, I still got the same error message.

Comment: Change the file association for js files to notepad. If you still have problems then redownload the Scite program or try using a different computer.